# Android long running activity / service

Tags: android, android-intent

I've built an application that uses the magnetic field sensor to act as a magnetic reed switch to run some methods in an activity. This runs 24/7, and the phone is not accessible to people, so there is no fear of user's closing the app. However, the app is crashing after prolonged waiting period; and I'm unsure if I've taken the right approach: activity based or service based.

My understanding of services is that they're good for background activities, but since my activity is always running I don't feel this is the right approach.

Likewise, since my activity runs in the background and since it constantly reading the magnetic field and creating local broadcast intents when needed, this may cause some problems with the various broadcast receivers (that is if they're not created during the onResume, and unregistered during onPause).

As I mentioned in the first paragraph, I'm wondering which is a preferred method to run the magnetic field sensor to fire off local broadcast intents.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok. If it's crashing what's the logs?

Well, you could still have a long running service that sends our messages for your activity. (A better appraoch) What's the point of having the sensor code in your activity? I understand that your activity is never paused, but you should still have a service that does the job.

Comment: The sensor code sends out a localbroadcast event to start methods in a singleton.

So even if the application doesn't close, using a service for long running activities, such as the sensor code, is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but I have learned through experience that Android reserves the right to kill off background activities at any time (ref: [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) docs). If you are are "foreground service" -- which implies you have an icon in the notification bar -- you're going to stick around a lot better: [Foreground Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). It's a very important concept for this type of app.